# Graphics tablet (Huion WH1409) loads driver properly but no input is received on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: input-devices, xinput, graphics-tablet

I am having issues with my graphics tablet (Huion WH1409) in Ubuntu 20.04. It has worked fine previously in Ubuntu, and largely functioned fine out of the box, no driver installs or configuration required.

Now it is simply giving no input. It shows up fine and the uclogic driver seems to load up properly.

Here is dmesg output when the tablet is plugged in:

```
[20986.273215] usb 3-4.1.3: new full-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[20986.412674] usb 3-4.1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=256c, idProduct=006e, bcdDevice= 0.00
[20986.412677] usb 3-4.1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=5, Product=6, SerialNumber=0
[20986.412680] usb 3-4.1.3: Product: PenTablet 
[20986.525040] input: PenTablet  Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:29:00.3/usb3/3-4/3-4.1/3-4.1.3/3-4.1.3:1.0/0003:256C:006E.000F/input/input34
[20986.525369] input: PenTablet  Pad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:29:00.3/usb3/3-4/3-4.1/3-4.1.3/3-4.1.3:1.0/0003:256C:006E.000F/input/input35
[20986.525529] uclogic 0003:256C:006E.000F: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keypad [PenTablet ] on usb-0000:29:00.3-4.1.3/input0
[20986.534645] input: PenTablet  Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:29:00.3/usb3/3-4/3-4.1/3-4.1.3/3-4.1.3:1.1/0003:256C:006E.0010/input/input36
[20986.534878] uclogic 0003:256C:006E.0010: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [PenTablet ] on usb-0000:29:00.3-4.1.3/input1
[20986.539404] input: PenTablet  Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:29:00.3/usb3/3-4/3-4.1/3-4.1.3/3-4.1.3:1.2/0003:256C:006E.0011/input/input38
[20986.597294] input: PenTablet  Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:29:00.3/usb3/3-4/3-4.1/3-4.1.3/3-4.1.3:1.2/0003:256C:006E.0011/input/input39
[20986.597392] input: PenTablet  System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:29:00.3/usb3/3-4/3-4.1/3-4.1.3/3-4.1.3:1.2/0003:256C:006E.0011/input/input40
[20986.597500] uclogic 0003:256C:006E.0011: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.0b Keyboard [PenTablet ] on usb-0000:29:00.3-4.1.3/input2
```

And here is the relevant portion of `xinput --list`

```
PenTablet  Pen stylus                       id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
PenTablet  Pad pad                          id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

`xev` shows no output for the pen or any of the buttons on the pen or tablet.

I have confirmed that the tablet works fine in windows, and it definitely worked in previous versions of ubuntu.

EDIT: I would also like to note that I used xorg to set the tablet to use the wacom driver which has also worked previously. Same thing happens, loads the driver fine, shows up in xsetwacom, but no input is received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by disconnecting the usb cable and using the wireless adapter instead. This is a known bug, see: https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers/issues/317

Comment: For me, the USB cable works with digimend version 10